# Leaflet sidebar - disable sidetab popout

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, sidebar

I have seen this code snippet somewhere but battling to source it and maybe someone can assist. See image below of what I have currently. What I would like to achieve is using the side bar icon (spanner in my example) to trigger something else (an alert is fine for now) and NOT bring out the sidebar as per default.

[image]

sidebar.close() triggered in a function called from this doesnt help; as in it still pops out

```html
<li><a href="#deviceconfig" role="tab"><i class="fa fa-cogs" onclick="test()"></i></a></li><div class="line-separator"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as I explained in the pull-request you [forgot to link to](https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2/pull/68), you have to give the `li` the class `sidebar-button` and then connect a click event to the nested link.

So, something like:

```
<li class='sidebar-button'>
  <a href="#" id="deviceconfig"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></a>
</li>
```

and then attach an event as follows:

```
$('a#deviceconfig').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation(); 
  alert('something'); 
})
```

or even simpler:

```
<li class='sidebar-button'>
  <a href="#" onclick="alert('something'); return false;"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></a>
</li>
```

Comment: You are a legend! Thanks a stack, side note... now that I have "my own" version of this js when will it get merged into the main http://turbo87.github.io/sidebar-v2/js/leaflet-sidebar.js file? If at all? Just need to remember then never to update as I have my own custom version

Comment: I just made the branch merge-ready, so I expect some feedback maybe, and assume then it will be merged in :) Time-frame unknown, this is open source :)